# Android InflateException

Tags: android, menu, inflate-exception

Here is crash log, that I received from Crittercism. I don't know exactly when it occurred. I was checked all menu files in project but not found any issue.
Crash log: http://pastebin.com/ZnEsFxKs

```
0 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.ExpandedMenuView
1 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
2 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
3 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:470)
4 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
5 at e.a(ListMenuPresenter.java:102)
6 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$PanelFeatureState.getListMenuView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1501)
7 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.initializePanelContent(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:930)
8 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.openPanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:821)
9 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.onCreatePanelView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:492)
10 at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreatePanelView(ActionBarActivity.java:147)
```

UPDATE1: I found other similar crash reports in Crittercism but with other resource "drawable not found resource": dividerHorizontal = 0x7f0100e0.
UPDATE2: All crashes occurred on Samsung devices.

Comment: Is it working normally, at your phone/tablet? If not, check for propely attached dependencies in android project, and if thats done right, check the proguard configuration if you use it  - it like to delete useful classes

Comment: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f0100e0 a=-1}`. It seems you are forgetting to declare a resource?

Comment: @joaquin 0x7f0100e0 is textColorSearchUrl in R.java, but I'm not used this resource in my app source code.